# How to click on a pictorial button in web browser page using python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<li id="tb_7" class="siebui-toolbar-enable" data-cmd="#15" data-subtoolbar="N" role="menuitem" 
title="Site Map" name="SiteMap" tabindex="-1" data-tbindex="7" data-autom="find:[ot]"><span 
class="siebui-icon-tb-sitemap ToolbarButtonOn"><img src="images/icon_sitemap_1.gif"><span 
class="siebui-toolbar-text">Site Map</span></span></li>
```

I have tried with below code which let me in to application after successful login but getting error (at bottom):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

username = 'abc'
password = '****'
url = 'someurl.com'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name('UserName').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('Password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('s_22').click()
wait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Site 
Map']"))).click()'''
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Do you have the correct text -  "Site Map"  in your XPath selector ? When i copy from your code I got 2 spaces instead of 1 space.

Comment: Can you provide the remaining of error message?

Comment: @Raymond full error mesage:

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/Desktop/Others/Practise/trail.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/Others/Practise/trail.py", line 15, in <module>
    wait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Site Map']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You can induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.siebui-toolbar-enable[name='SiteMap'][title='Site Map']>span.siebui-icon-tb-sitemap.ToolbarButtonOn>img[src*='images/icon_sitemap_1']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='siebui-toolbar-enable' and @name='SiteMap'][@title='Site Map']/span[@class='siebui-icon-tb-sitemap ToolbarButtonOn']/img[contains(@src, 'images/icon_sitemap_1')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB i have tried but no luck failing with same error:(

Comment: Error:
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: